# ajax form using information from current post - wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, jquery

I'm following this [tutorial](http://byronyasgur.wordpress.com/2011/06/27/frontend-forward-facing-ajax-in-wordpress/) to use front-end ajax to submit an email from a form and include information such as the current post title in the email. Please note I'm not an expert of php or ajax. Any advice or resources would be appreciated.

I tried the following - but my hidden input field value below only returns a string, I assume this is because it gets included after the page loads.

Jquery

```
function submit_me(){
jQuery.post(the_ajax_script.ajaxurl, jQuery("#theForm").serialize()
,
function(response_from_the_action_function){
jQuery("#response_area").html(response_from_the_action_function);
}
);
}
```

PHP

```
// enqueue and localise scripts
function plugin_enqueue_scripts() {
 wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-handle', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'ajax.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
 wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-handle', 'the_ajax_script', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'plugin_enqueue_scripts');


 // THE AJAX ADD ACTIONS
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_the_ajax_hook', 'the_action_function' );
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_the_ajax_hook', 'the_action_function' ); // need this to serve non logged in users
 // THE FUNCTION
 function the_action_function(){
 /* this area is very simple but being serverside it affords the possibility of retreiving data from the server and passing it back to the javascript function */
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $title = $_POST['title'];

 echo"Title: " . $title;// this is passed back to the javascript function
 die();// wordpress may print out a spurious zero without this - can be particularly bad if using json
 }
 // ADD EG A FORM TO THE PAGE
 function hello_world_ajax_frontend(){
 $the_form = '
 <form id="theForm">
 <input id="name" name="name" value = "name" type="text" />
 <input name="action" type="hidden" value="the_ajax_hook" />&nbsp; <!-- this puts the action the_ajax_hook into the serialized form -->
 <input id="submit_button" value = "Click This" type="button" onClick="submit_me();" />
 <input name="title" type="hidden" value="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
 </form>
 <div id="response_area">
 This is where we\'ll get the response
 </div>';
 return $the_form;
 }
 add_shortcode("hw_ajax_frontend", "hello_world_ajax_frontend");
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
function hello_world_ajax_frontend(){
 $the_form = '
 <form id="theForm">
 <input id="name" name="name" value = "name" type="text" />
 <input name="action" type="hidden" value="the_ajax_hook" />&nbsp; <!-- this puts the action the_ajax_hook into the serialized form -->
 <input id="submit_button" value = "Click This" type="button" onClick="submit_me();" />
 <input name="title" type="hidden" value="'.get_the_title().'" />
 </form>
 <div id="response_area">
 This is where we\'ll get the response
 </div>';
 return $the_form;
 }
```

Basically, just concatenate the result of `get_the_title()` with your html output.

If you leave your php code block inside the string, it won't be executed and your php code will be outputed to the html doc.

Comment: Thank you 
I tried this but the problem is using the_title() returns no value.
Using get_the_title(); works beautifully.

Answer (score 2):

Updated:

Instead of `<?php the_title(); ?>` try `' . get_the_title() . '`

Comment: Still produces a string.
<input name="title" type="hidden" value="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" />

Comment: `get_the_title();` does return title as string. Is string is blank? What is your expected result?

Comment: Glad that you have found the solution.